# Rails seed migrate is being stopped with an error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying to do `rake db:seed` which normally works for me but now is failing.

Here is the error and the code.

My error logs:
[image]

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
cattr_accessor :current_user        
belongs_to :highschool, optional: true
end
```

High school migration:

```
class CreateHighschools < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :highschools do |t|
  t.string :secondaryschool

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

High School migration reference to User:

```
class AddHighschoolRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
add_reference :users, :highschools, foreign_key: true
end
end
```

Highschool.rb:

```
class Highschool < ApplicationRecord
has_many :users
end
```

Highschools_controller.rb:

```
class HighschoolsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
def create
   @highschool = Highschool.new(highschool_params)
   if @highschool.save
  render json: @highschool
else
  render json: {errors: @highschool.errors.full_messages}
end
end
private
  def highschool_params
params.require(:highschool).permit(:secondaryschool)
end
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
 create_table "highschools", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "secondaryschool"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end
```

Seeds.rb:

```
Highschool.destroy_all
special = Highschool.create!(Secondaryschool: "Stuyvesant High School")
special2 = Highschool.create!(Secondaryschool: "Brooklyn Tech")
special3 = Highschool.create!(Secondaryschool: "Bronx Science")
```

Comment: Don't use an image for information like errors, data or code. Links can rot and break, removing information essential to the question. Also, we can't reuse the information; Often we search for parts of the error, and that forces us to type it in rather than copy/paste. Also the search engines can't index images, making it harder for others to find your question when searching for help with the same problem. Remember, SO isn't as much about answering helping you as it is about helping those in the future with the same question.

Comment: Great points, I'll make sure to do that going forward @theTinMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a typo:

```
special = Highschool.create!(secondaryschool: "Stuyvesant High School")
special2 = Highschool.create!(secondaryschool: "Brooklyn Tech")
special3 = Highschool.create!(secondaryschool: "Bronx Science")
```

Comment: that capital "S" is the thing that is throwing it off?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much @uDay!!

Comment: Glad it helped you! mark it as answer if its fixed. :)

Comment: Rather than prompt the OP to accept your answer, it's considered better form to wait a couple days to see if the OP has selected an answer. If not, put a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer as a comment to the original question. SO is a world-wide site and it takes a little while for all the users to see a question and respond, with potentially better answers. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271815/128421 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/128421.

Comment: I just said that coz answerers can move on to next question. I have seen this practice so thought of doing it too..

Comment: @theTinMan though I didn't force the OP to accept it. I just suggested if it has solved his problem/criteria ;)

Comment: @uDaY quick question some thing i noticed in my rails console was that my highschools_id: nil even though on the front end it looks nice, do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Never mind figured it - i forgot to include it in my application controller :)